# NameError at /contact/ name 'ContactForm' is not defined error:

Tags: django

I am creating a contact page where an email is sent to the user. When I go to access the contact page I run into the error "NameError at /contact/ name 'ContactForm' is not defined"

Any idea?

Code:

```
def Contact(request):
    Contact_Form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Contact_Form(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
            contact_content = request.POST.get('content')

            template = get_template('/contact_form.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name' : contact_name,
                'contact_email' : contact_email,
                'contact_content' : contact_content,
            }

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form email",
                content,
                "Creative web" + '',
                ['servwishes@gmail.com'],
                headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
            )
enter code here
            email.send()

            return redirect('blog:success')
    return render(request, 'users/contact.html', {'form':Contact_Form })
```

Comment: You either haven’t defined the form or you haven’t imported it properly. You haven’t shown your imports or project layout so we can’t tell what the import should be, but it will be something like `from .forms import ContactForm`

Comment: As an aside, you don’t need `Contact_Form = ContactForm`, just use `ContactForm` everywhere in the view. Add an else block underneath the `if request.method == 'POST':` and add `form = Contact_Form()`. Then the template context should be `{'form': form}`. Finally, in Python you would normally use `def contact(request):` instead of `def Contact(request):` for a function.

Comment: Hi thank you for the feedback!

These are my imports:

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, ContactForm

I cannot see the errors in the view so just a bit stuck, my urls are ok, would you suggesr anywhere else to look?

Comment: The `from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, ContactForm` should work. Maybe you're not running the code you think you are. Make sure you've saved any changes to the files, checked in and pulled changes if you're deploying on a different server, and restarted the server.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for your help!

I just got it!